# What is the earliest canon law reference that contraceptive intercourse does not consummate a marriage?

Tags: catholicism, church-history, marriage, canon-law, contraception

What is the earliest canon law reference that contraceptive intercourse does not consummate a marriage?

Fr. Hardon, S.J., defines "[consummated marriage](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/72172/1787)" as

> A marriage in which after the matrimonial contract is made husband and wife have marital intercourse. **Contraceptive intercourse does not consummate Christian marriage.** (Etym. Latin *consummare*, to bring into one sum, to perfect.)

Comment: Related Consideration : Does the lack of consummation in a marriage make that marriage void ? If both parties agree to a non-consummated marriage, is such a marriage union considered void by other, third, parties ? Would a marriage not consummated by means of mutual celibacy, be considered void ?

Comment: I don't have time to write a proper answer at the moment, but if you are interested you might want to start with current canon law: https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib4-cann998-1165_en.html#TITLE_VII.

Comment: Or if you knowingly marry someone that is infertile, what difference between that and contraception?

Comment: @NigelJ [Intercourse (consummation) is not required for the validity of a marriage.](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/72172/1787) For your other questions, see Ford, S.J., [_The Validity of Virginal Marriage_](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6920).

Comment: @MikeBorden The natures of the acts are very different, even though the effects of the acts might be the same. Contraceptive intercourse is "exercised in such a way that the act is deliberately frustrated in its natural power to generate life" ([_Casti Connubii_](https://www.vatican.va/content/pius-xi/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xi_enc_19301231_casti-connubii.html) §56), whereas the "conjugal act is destined primarily by nature for the begetting of children" (§54).